# How do I handle EndProcess events in a Vista Console app?

Tags: windows-vista, console

I have a console application.  In XP, I can use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` to register a callback that receives `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, `CTRL_C_EVENT` and a few others. It works great. When the callback is called I can cleanup before I return from the call. Problem is, `SetConsoleCtrlHanlder()` is not supported in Vista.   Now what?

Answer (score 1):

SetConsoleCtrlHandler has worked just fine for me on Vista, and there's no indication on [its MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016(VS.85).aspx) that it shouldn't.

Are you having difficulty getting the same code to work on a Vista system?  If so, what failure mode / error codes are you seeing?